# get_object() method instead of get_initial() in createview to pre fill form?

Tags: python-3.5, django-class-based-views, django-2.0

Is it possible to pre fill Django form using get_object method instead of get_initial when using CreateView. I am trying to clone (all attributes will be same except primary key) an entry in the database table. Not using UpdateView since it will not be updating the existing record. Or is there any other way to approach this?

```
    class RequestCloneView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
        model = Request
        form_class = RequestAddForm
        http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
        template_name = 'request_add.html'
        success_message = "Request Created!"
        def get_initial(self):
            initial_data = super(RequestCloneView, self).get_initial()
            data = Request.objects.get(req_id=self.kwargs['qid'])
            initial_data['req_label'] = data.req_label
            initial_data['model'] = data.model
            initial_data['version'] = data.version
            initial_data['type'] = data.type
            initial_data['test'] = data.test
            return initial
        # def get_object(self):
        #     return Request.objects.get(req_id=self.kwargs['qid'])
        ...
```

It is working for me but wanted to know if we can use get_object like we do for UpdateView to pre populate form instead of assigning each value to initial_data dictionary manually? Or any other better way to do it?